# Python: (findall, wide to long, pandas): Data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, findall

So, I am trying to pivot this data ([link here](https://www.ers.usda.gov/webdocs/DataFiles/48747/PopulationEstimates.xls?v=3011.3)) to where all the metrics/numbers are in a column with another column being the ID column. Obviously having a ton of data/metrics in a bunch of columns is much harder to compare and do calculations off of than having it all in one column.

So, I know what tools I need for this; Pandas, Findall, Wide_to_long (or melt) and maybe stack. However, I am having a bit of difficulty putting them all in the right place.

I easily can import the data into the df and view it, but when it comes to using findall with wide_to_long to pivot the data I get pretty confused. I am basing my idea off of this [example](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) (about half way down when they use the findall / regex to define new column names). I am looking to create a new column for each category of the metrics (ie. population estimate is one column and then % change is another, they should not be all one column)

Can someone help me set up the syntax correctly for this part? I am not good at the expressions dealing with pattern recognition.

Thank you.